# Buggy Virtualscene Rear Camera Android Studio Emulator using ARCore

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, arcore

I am a newbie to ARCore development with Sceneform using Android Studio. As I don't have any compatible device, I am trying to test the development using the built-in emulator but the rear camera (set to Virtualscene) seems to be buggy as the scene will frequently distorted.

Tried with several different ARCore sample programs, and emulated different android devices (Pixel 2 XL API 28, Pixel 2 XL API 27 & Pixel API 27), but still facing the same problem. OpenGL has been set to renderer maximum (Up to 3.1).

I suspect it is due to hardware limitation, but is there any way that I can solve this problem? Thanks.

**My laptop specs:**

OS: Windows 10 Home

CPU: Intel Core i5-7200U @ 2.5GHz

RAM: 8.0GB DDR4

GPU: Intel HD Graphics 620

**Sample of the emulator bug:**
[image: Sample of buggy emulator]

**Logcat snippet:**

> 08-09 03:22:28.521 5289-5289/com.google.ar.sceneform.samples.solarsystem E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008919
>   08-09 03:22:28.593 5289-5289/com.google.ar.sceneform.samples.solarsystem W/native: cameras.cc:526 Metadata for GL texture didn't arrive. camera_id=0 status=generic::deadline_exceeded: Timed out waiting for metadata.
>   08-09 03:22:28.596 5289-5335/com.google.ar.sceneform.samples.solarsystem E/native: camera_image_stream.cc:115 Failed to extract the metadata or correct the timestamp, status=generic::deadline_exceeded: Timed out waiting for metadata.
>   08-09 03:22:28.600 5289-5289/com.google.ar.sceneform.samples.solarsystem E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008919
>   08-09 03:22:28.602 5289-5289/com.google.ar.sceneform.samples.solarsystem E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008919
>   08-09 03:22:28.630 5289-5335/com.google.ar.sceneform.samples.solarsystem E/native: camera_image_stream.cc:115 Failed to extract the metadata or correct the timestamp, status=generic::deadline_exceeded: Timed out waiting for metadata.
>   08-09 03:22:28.657 5289-5289/com.google.ar.sceneform.samples.solarsystem W/native: cameras.cc:526 Metadata for GL texture didn't arrive. camera_id=0 status=generic::deadline_exceeded: Timed out waiting for metadata.
>   08-09 03:22:28.662 5289-5289/com.google.ar.sceneform.samples.solarsystem E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008919

Comment: I don't think its because of your hardware. I have a '17 Macbook Pro and I too am facing the same issue. The camera tilts on one side if I move around a lot & is really slow.

Comment: @Clinkz, do you have any solution to it?

Comment: No, sorry. Can't help.

Comment: @Clinkz i see. thanks anyway

Comment: Refer [this](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/148) link. If you're running a Windows machine, this ought to fix the problem.

Comment: thanks a lot! downloaded the file, and the emulator seems smoother but sometimes still buggy. looked into the SDK manager, seems like the official emulator 28 isn't available yet. :)

Comment: Official won't be available until a few weeks. However, this fix is available in the latest canary build. Give it a week or two. Since they're aware, they'll get a fix out soon.

Answer (score 1):

For your CPU you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator) that need a support for Intel VT-x, **maybe is disable**. You can see on this [post](https://communities.intel.com/thread/116865) how to enable.

Other option is maybe let the emulator use more **RAM**.

`Tools > Android > AVD Manager`

Click in a pen to edit your AVD and in the new dialog click on `Show Advanced Settings`

Comment: thanks for sharing the link. tried that, and it seems like VT-x already enabled. tried to increase the emulator RAM to 2GB but still facing the problem.

Comment: @programmerdreamer check one thing please. Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Platform. Select "Show Package Details". Is "Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image" downloaded for API 27/26?

Comment: downloaded for API 27 but not 26 because I'm using API 27 as the AVD. I noticed one thing though, after increasing the RAM allocation to 6GB & VM heap to 4GB it become smoother, but will still be distorted, especially when the app starting to detect a plane. is the RAM allocation usually need that big?

Comment: @programmerdreamer should not be so big by default. Even you already has the needed for ARCore Emulator, but maybe another  back programs are making this slower. AS is heavy, the emulator heavier and the ARCore even more heavy hahaha. Try to analyse you CPU/RAM while running.

Comment: yup it is indeed heavy. my CPU usage will shoot to >85% when running the emulator, not to mention the RAM usage would be used around that same % too.

Comment: @programmerdreamer this is sad, but even in my company they decide to buy a new pixel and S9 only for tests. The nexus 6p is already with some delay of processing. Maybe you can try to run the emulator by terminal with the AS close? Not the best solution, but is some solution.

Comment: haven't tried that yet, just borrowed my friend's phone to run the testing huhu